# How to connect to AWS RDS PostgreSql Instance from AWS CLI

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, psql

How to connect to AWS RDS PostgreSql Instance from AWS CLI.
From command line using psql command we can connect. But wanted to know if there is a way to connect from AWC CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. The AWS CLI is for interacting with the AWS API. You would use a PostgreSQL client for connecting to a PostgreSQL server.